# add_action(updated_postmeta) to run update_post_meta -> loop

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I have an add_action that triggers on a postmeta table change.
When triggered, I need to update the post_meta table with the function update_post_meta().

As you can expect, this results in a loop, continuously updating the post meta table.

Does anyone know how to break the loop in this case and run only once?

```
function seoHomepageTitle() {
  $page = get_page_by_title("Homepage");
  $meta_key = "_yoast_wpseo_title";
  $meta_value = jet_engine()->listings->data->get_option( 'pwp-options::seo-title-homepage' );

  isset($page, $meta_value) ? update_post_meta($page->ID , $meta_key, $meta_value) : false;

  return;
}

add_action('updated_postmeta', 'seoHomepageTitle');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the hook before updating, then adding it back like this

```
function seoHomepageTitle() {
  $page = get_page_by_title("Homepage");
  $meta_key = "_yoast_wpseo_title";
  $meta_value = jet_engine()->listings->data->get_option( 'pwp-options::seo-title-homepage' );
  
  remove_action('updated_postmeta', 'seoHomepageTitle');
 
  isset($page, $meta_value) ? update_post_meta($page->ID , $meta_key, $meta_value) : false;

  //add_action('updated_postmeta', 'seoHomepageTitle');
  return;
}

add_action('updated_postmeta', 'seoHomepageTitle');
```

Comment: I am really confused... I trigger updated_postmeta by a field added from my form (meta_key: '_rendered_form'). I used the addition to the function you described, but every time, 160 new rows are added to wp_postmeta, all with different meta_id's, same post_id, same meta_key (_yoast_wpseo_title) and same meta_value as added in my form... I can't find why this function is constantly triggered 160 times... the form submits via AJAX, but I also tried with a pagerefresh..

Comment: Comment out the `add_action` in the function like I updated in the answer above, I think it's because this runs for every meta change, so it seems like you have about 150 meta values changing on each request, so this fix would make it only run on the first one

Comment: thnx, it keeps addig 160 new rows. What I expect (since I use a form plugin) is that the INSERT SQL is run 160 times on insert. I am now trying to log the SQL injections in MariaDB and see if that is true.

Comment: What I can also do is first retreive the last meta value on '_yoast_wpseo_title', and if the data is already added, abort the script.

Comment: It is working! I did add the add_action back. I will mark your answer as 'answer'. Thanks a lot!